# Use the sufficient conditions for differentiability to determine where the function $f(z) = e^{z^2}$ is differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I know that the exponential function satisfies the condition of Cauchy-Riemann and is differentiable but how to tell where the function is differentiable specifically?
Sufficient Conditions for Differentiability in this case are: If the real functions u(x,y) and v(x, y) are continuous and have continuous first-order partial derivatives in some neighborhood of a point z, and if u and v satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations at z, then the complex function f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y) is differentiable at z

Comment: Just the phrase "f is differentiable" with no conditions means it is differentiable **where**?

Comment: Do we have tell the values of x and y at which it differentiates or something else?

Answer (score 0):

That function can be naturally expressed as the composition of two differentiable maps (the exponential function and $z\mapsto z^2$). Therefore, it is differentiable. You don't need the Cauchy-Riemann equations here.